# Is there any way to ensure that multiple web requests are handled by same Kubernetes pod?

Tags: javascript, kubernetes

We have use case to upload a large file by splitting it into multiple chunks. We have implemented it using javascript and created an array of promises with the required web requests and we are waiting to execute all of them in parallel using Promise.All. These web requests are handled by multiple Kubernetes pods. Is there a way to ensure that same pod accepts all the requests of the same user for a file upload?

We have tried the above file upload approach as a POC and want more clarity how the requests will be handled by the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're looking at Session Affinity. This can be done at the service/loadbalancer level, or at the ingress controller level, depending on how you've setup your service.

To set up session affinity on the loadbalancer level (i.e. your kubernetes service is direction facing the outside world), see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity). Also be aware of the session stickiness as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-stickiness-timeout)

To set up session affinity on the ingress controller level, look at the documentation for your ingress controller. For the nginx controller, see [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#session-affinity)